# How to use micronaut rabbitmq client with BuiltinExchangeType TOPIC

Tags: rabbitmq, micronaut

I would like to use micronaut-rabbitmq to send messages between services via topics.
Therefore I've created an exchange, queues and bindings in the ChannelInitializer like this:

```
channel.exchangeDeclare("registration", BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC, true)
channel.queueDeclare("user_new", true, false, false, null)
channel.queueBind("user_new", "registration", "user.new.#")


channel.queueDeclare("user_all", true, false, false, null)
channel.queueBind("user_all", "registration", "user.#")
```

When I try to send a message to the routingkey "user.new" it is not send to any of the queues.

```
@Binding("user.new")
override fun userCreated(event: UserCreatedEvent)
```

I would expect, that it is send to both of the queues because of the topics routingkeys.

If I rename the "user_new" queue to "user.new" the message is send to this queue. But as I want to have the message in both queues this is no option.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was, that I didn't declare the exchange on the `@RabbitClient`

After changing `@RabbitClient` to `@RabbitClient("registration")` everything works perfectly.

Comment: MrBorsti, do you have some sample code? I find myself in the position where the ChannelInitializer.initialize method is not invoked at all.

Also, if I have multiple connections (rabbitmq.servers.serverA.uri), how I make sure to create the exchange and queue on the correct server? Thanks.